# How to identify Stripe customers who started a payment subscription after trial ends

Tags: stripe-payments

Is there an specific API endpoint or events that triggers when for example a customer is in a trial period and ended paying the first subscription invoice?

In short, I would like to track customers who paid the first subscription after a trial ends.

I'm thinking to do this processing on my end where I would listen to `customer.subscription.trial_will_end` webhook event and mark them on a table and once a `invoice.payment_succeeded` event happens I can check the same table who came from a trial. But if there's any recommended way to do this from the API alone it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I would just listen to `invoice.payment_succeeded` and check two things :

1. the `billing_reason` is `subscription_update` (in order to filter out invoices from creating a subscription for example) https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-billing_reason
2. retrieve the related subscription object(`invoice.subscription`) and check that `trial_end == current_period_start` https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-current_period_start + https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-trial_end

When a trial ends it starts a new billing cycle, and `trial_end` is the time that most recent trial ended so this should always hold when you're looking at an event like this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a stripe event that you can listen to in your webhook: customer.subscription.updated.

You can use the subscription status field. When the customer pays for the first time the status changes from "trialing" to "active".